# After authorizing the oauth how can i send a tweet from Python shell?

Tags: python, twitter

You may now access protected resources using the access tokens above. It says this on python.Now what should i do in order to send a tweet? Could you please tell step by step? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're fine with using 3rd-party libraries, so first, install [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy):

```
$ pip install tweepy
```

There are [other](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter) [great](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) Twitter API wrappers out there, but I think [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) can get you from OAuth authentication to status update using the least amount of code. Just follow the example [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/oauth.py). I've also posted the gist of it below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# After registering your app you should be able to
# find these values on your application page.
# https://dev.twitter.com/apps/{your_app_id}/show
# Make sure your app's access level is "Read and Write",
# or you won't be able to post.
consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_token=""
access_token_secret=""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.update_status('Maybe you should try Googling next time!')
```

I think your question wouldn't have been downvoted so much if you had at least shown what you had achieved on your own, and what specific problems you were facing.